# Parse HTML from repeating JSON in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, json

I am trying to display the JSON response in a list view using Android Studio. However, I do not know how to handle the repeat JSON response.

Here is my JSON response:

{"response":  [{"dfirst_name":"Kelvin","dlast_name":"Cheung","medicine":"Amlodipine","start_date":"2016-03-02","end_date":"2016-03-06","dosage":"50mg","instructions":"4 times per day "},{"dfirst_name":"Simon","dlast_name":"Yam","medicine":"Amlodipine","start_date":"2016-05-09","end_date":"2016-05-19","dosage":"100mg","instructions":"2 times per day, extra dosage"},

And here is a snippet of the showJSON() in my android studio project.

private void showJSON(String response){

```
    String first_name="";
    String last_name="";
    String nationality="";
    String hkid="";
    String dob="";
    String age="";
    String gender="";
    String bloodtype="";
    String emergency_contact="";
    String relationship="";
    String mobile="";
    String food_algy="";
    String drug_algy="";
    String dfirst_name="";
    String dlast_name="";
    String medicine="";
    String start_date="";
    String end_date="";
    String dosage="";
    String instructions="";
    String in_date="";
    String out_date="";


    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);

        first_name = c.getString(Config.KEY_FIRST_NAME);
        last_name = c.getString(Config.KEY_LAST_NAME);
        nationality = c.getString(Config.KEY_NATIONALITY);
        hkid = c.getString(Config.KEY_HKID);
        dob = c.getString(Config.KEY_DOB);
        age = c.getString(Config.KEY_AGE);
        gender = c.getString(Config.KEY_GENDER);
        bloodtype = c.getString(Config.KEY_BLOODTYPE);
        emergency_contact = c.getString(Config.KEY_EMERGENCYCONTACT);
        relationship = c.getString(Config.KEY_RELATIONSHIP);
        mobile = c.getString(Config.KEY_MOBILE);
        in_date = c.getString(Config.KEY_IN_DATE);
        out_date = c.getString(Config.KEY_OUT_DATE);
        food_algy = c.getString(Config.KEY_FOOD_ALGY);
        drug_algy = c.getString(Config.KEY_DRUG_ALGY);

        dfirst_name = c.getString(Config.KEY_DFIRST_NAME);
        dlast_name = c.getString(Config.KEY_DLAST_NAME);
        medicine = c.getString(Config.KEY_MEDICINE);
        start_date = c.getString(Config.KEY_START_DATE);
        end_date = c.getString(Config.KEY_END_DATE);
        dosage = c.getString(Config.KEY_DOSAGE);
        instructions = c.getString(Config.KEY_INSTRUCTIONS);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    textViewResult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    textViewResult.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=4><b>General Information: </b></font><br> " +
                                         "<font size=4>Name: </font>" + first_name + " "+ last_name + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Nationality: </font>" + nationality + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>HKID: </font>" + hkid + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Date of Birth: </font>" + dob + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Age: </font>" + age + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Gender: </font>" + gender + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Blood Type: </font>" + bloodtype + "<br><br>" +
                                         "<font size=2><b>Allergies: </b></font><br>" +
                                         "<font size=4>Food Allergy: </font>" + food_algy +"<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Drug Allergy: </font>" + drug_algy +"<br><br>"+
                                        "<font size=2><b>Admission History: </b></font><br>" +

                                        "<font size=4>Admitted on: </font>" + in_date +"<br>"+
                                        "<font size=4 >Discharged on: </font>" + out_date +"<br><br>"+
                                         "<font size=2><b>Emergency Contact: </b></font><br>" +
                                         "<font size=4>Contact Person: </font>" + emergency_contact +"<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Relationship: </font>" + relationship + "<br>"+
                                         "<font size=4>Mobile: </font>" + mobile));

}
```

Up to this point, I can output all other information as expected in 'textViewResult.setText()' because the JSON response of those information are non-repetitive.

Can someone help and show me how to loop through the repeating JSON repsponse and output it in a similar format as other information.

Comment: You want to loop through each people in your JSON response? Is that what you mean by repetitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote something that I can't test right now. Tell me if it works for you.

Basically I loop through the result array and append the data to the text view.

```
private void showJSON(String response){
    try {
        String html = "";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

        for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);

            html = "<font size=4><b>General Information: </b></font><br> " +
                   "<font size=4>Name: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_FIRST_NAME) + " "+ c.getString(Config.KEY_LAST_NAME) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Nationality: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_NATIONALITY) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>HKID: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_HKID) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Date of Birth: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_DOB) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Age: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_AGE) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Gender: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_GENDER) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Blood Type: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_BLOODTYPE) + "<br><br>" +
                   "<font size=2><b>Allergies: </b></font><br>" +
                   "<font size=4>Food Allergy: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_FOOD_ALGY) +"<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Drug Allergy: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_DRUG_ALGY) +"<br><br>"+
                   "<font size=2><b>Admission History: </b></font><br>" +
                   "<font size=4>Admitted on: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_IN_DATE) +"<br>"+
                   "<font size=4 >Discharged on: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_OUT_DATE) +"<br><br>"+
                   "<font size=2><b>Emergency Contact: </b></font><br>" +
                   "<font size=4>Contact Person: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_EMERGENCYCONTACT) +"<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Relationship: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_RELATIONSHIP) + "<br>"+
                   "<font size=4>Mobile: </font>" + c.getString(Config.KEY_MOBILE);

            textViewResult.append(Html.fromHtml(html));
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are hardcodes as object

```
 JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
```

try to use for-Loop

```
for(int i=0;i<=array.length;i++) { 
   JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(i);   
}
```

and add this data to arraylist.
check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Thanks for your help!!